# Ionic 2 : clear ion-tab navigation history

Tags: navigation, ionic2

I have a page with 5 tabs. I can navigate into a tab say tab 1 and then if I change the tab and come back to the previous tab, Previous tab (tab 1) navigation stack is maintained.

I want to clear out this navigation stack....

```
Sequence of events:

1) By default Tab 1 is showing with list of items 
2). I click on the item , go into the item detail and now back button is displayed 
3). Now I'm  moving to the second tab. 
4). finally moving to the first tab. Here again I see the item detail with the back button.
```

I want this state to be cleared.

Any help Guys!!

Comment: Its hard to say without your code. May be the reason could be you have not set your page as rootPage on navigation or you might have used ion-navbar in your ion-header rather than using ion-toolbar